# Named Pipes, using Fork()

Tags: c, fork, gnu, named-pipes, fifo

I got a pretty big problem. So for my assignment I have to use named pipes (FIFO) and using Fork(). I have three programs, lab6(which is my main/parent/print answers) then I have my lifesupport(Which is a child) and then I have my navigation(which is also a child). The two children has to write to the parent and the parent will read it and print it out. It's really hard to explain how the answer should be. Its complicated, but I got my math right, I only ran into problems when I tried moving this file into separate FIFO files. I'm getting segmentation fault errors. So my question is what am I doing wrong?? I'm trying to turn this code into a FIFO. p.s. don't worry about any of the time or seed generator or anything like that. I just need the navigation to calculate its part and send it to the parent and same goes with lifesupport, but I can't seem to get the FIFO working.

main file-

```
  #include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<sys/stat.h>
  #include<linux/stat.h>

 #define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"         //default is current directory


 void getTime();
 void writeToMain( char *, int );
 void lifeSupport();
  void navigation();
 int generate(int);
  void countdown( int );

 //Global Variables
  const int MAX_LINE = 80;
  int ret, myPipes[2];
   char *message;

 int time_;
  char myClock[25];

 //Pipe variables
  int totalTime = 0;
  char toSend[120];



int main(void){

    FILE *fpoint;
    char readbuffer[80];
    int again = 1;


    mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

    while(again){

    fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
    fgets(readbuffer, 80, fpoint);
    printf("recevived string: %s\n, readbuffer");
    fclose(fpoint);
    if(strcmp(readbuffer, "stop") == 0 ) again = 0;

    return(0);

            }


              if( ret == 0 ){
            if(fork() == 0){

                    while (repeat){

                            totalTime = 0;
                             getTime();
                            lifeSupport();
                            navigation();

                            getTime();
                            sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] \tSleep \t\t[ %d  second(s) ]\n", myClock, 30 - totalTime);
                            write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );

                            sleep(30 - totalTime);
                    }
            }

            else{

                    while(again){
                    read( myPipes[PipeStdIn], buffer, MAX_LINE);
                    again = strcmp(buffer, "Stop");


                    if (again == 0) ;
                            else
                                printf("%s \n", buffer);
                     }

            }
         }//exit main
```

Child (life Support)-

```
       #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    #include<linux/stat.h>
    #define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"



    void getTime();
    void writeToMain( char *, int );
    void lifeSupport();
    void navigation();
    int generate(int);
    void countdown( int );

    void lifeSupport(){
            getTime();
            message = "Beginning life support systems \t";
            sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s ", myClock, message);
            write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
            sleep(1);
            totalTime ++;

            getTime();
            time_ = generate(5);
            message = "Adjusting breathing gas levels";
            sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s  \t[ %d Second(s) ]", myClock, message, time_);
            write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
            sleep(time_);
      totalTime += time_;

             getTime();
            time_ = generate(3);
            message = "Adjusting environment";
            sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s  \t\t[ %d Second(s) ]", myClock, message, time_);
            write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
            sleep(time_);
            totalTime += time_;

            getTime();
            message = "Done. Life support adjusted. \t[ 1 Second(s) ]";
            sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s ", myClock, message);
            write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
            sleep(1);
            totalTime ++;

             getTime();
            message = "\t\tExecution time";
            sprintf(toSend, "%s [ %d Second(s) ]\n", message, (totalTime - 1));
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(1);
    totalTime ++;


            FILE *fpoint;
            int again =1;
            char strIn[80] = "Use message from command line";

            if(argc !=2){
         printf("USAGE: NamedPipeClient[string]\n");
                    exit(1);
                    }

            while(again == 1){

            if((fpoint = fopen (FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
                    perror("fopen");
                    exit(1);

            if((fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
                    perror("fopen");
                    exit(1);
                            }
                    }
            }
```

and last child (navigation. Remember that both children write to the parent)-

```
       #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    #include<linux/stat.h>
    #define FIFO_FILE "MYFIFO"


    void getTime();
    void writeToMain( char *, int );
    void lifeSupport();
    void navigation();
    int generate(int);
    void countdown( int );

    void navigation(){
    getTime();
    message = "Beginning navigation systems";
    sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s \t[ 1 Second(s) ]", myClock, message);
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(1);
    totalTime ++;

    getTime();
    time_ = generate(6);
    message = "Adjusting navigation systems";
    sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s  \t[ %d Second(s) ]", myClock, message, time_);
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(time_);
    totalTime += time_;
           getTime();
    message = "Done. Navigation systems adjusted \t[ 1 Second(s) ]";
    sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s ", myClock, message);
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(1);
    totalTime ++;

    message = "\t\tExecution time";
    sprintf(toSend, "%s  [ %d Second(s) ]", message, (totalTime - 2));
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(1);
    totalTime += 2;

    getTime();
    message = "\tTotal time";
    sprintf(toSend, "[ %s ] %s \t[ %d Second(s) ]",  myClock, message, totalTime);
    write( myPipes[PipeStdOut], toSend, strlen(toSend) + 1 );
    sleep(1);



            while(again == 1){

            if((fpoint = fopen (FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
                    perror("fopen");
                    exit(1);
            }

            if((fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "w")) == NULL){
                 perror("fopen");
                    exit(1);
            }
    }
            fputs(strIn,fpoint);
            fclose(fpoint);

    return(0);
    }
```

I know this is alot and any help is greatly appericated. If this is too much I'll respect the rules and delete the question other than that, I think it'll be a decent challenge. lol 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do check the return values of `fopen()` and `fclose()`. Why didn't you do that for the other `f`functions?

Comment: What do you mean? @tofro

Comment: 1. No check of return value of `fgets()` in main reading from the FIFO. 2. nothing ever written to the FIFO in `lifeSupport`(unapparent why you would include it, the FIFO is only opened, nothing done with it), 3. no check of return values in `fputs()`writing to the FIFO in `navigation`-How do you want to know *what's* going wrong if you don't check for it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have tried to obfuscate your problem as much as possible to us. Your program example is *not* minimal - it boils down (main) to

```
int main (void){

   mknod(FIFO_FILE, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

   while(again){

      fpoint = fopen(FIFO_FILE, "r");
      fgets(readbuffer, 80, fpoint);
      printf("recevived string: %s\n, readbuffer");
      fclose(fpoint);

      // All the fork() stuff follows here
      ....
   }
```

You create the FIFO, open it and read from it (without checking that you actually got something). Whom are you expecting to have put something in there when your child processes that would actually do that haven't even been started?

Because you do not check the return value of `fgets()` you will be working on an uninitialized buffer (`readbuffer`) and here havoc starts.

Even **if** you had something external magically writing to the FIFO, you *need* to check the return value of `fgets()` especially in a multi-process environment - You cannot just assume the other process will already have written something when you read.